# Can't add reference of Windows Runtime Project into UWP app

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2017

I want to access the Windows Runtime Component from my UWP app. For it, I tried to add it as a reference. In Solution Explorer, right-clicked the References node under UWP app project and selected Add reference.

In the Reference Manager dialog, selected Projects->Solution. But I cant see my Windows runtime project there. It seems empty.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: As i understand you want open two project in one solution so you can do that, on that project screen where you find a empty list follow this > You will find a browse button in below right hand side locate your project through that button, if this is the solution you want reply me, i will post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a solution, then, I created a UWP project and a windows runtime component.

[image]

After that, I right-click my UWP project and add reference to my windows runtime component.

[image]

With this, I can add reference to my windows runtime component successfully.

If you want to add reference to an existing windows runtime component(.winmd), you could right-click your windows runtime component project and click "Open Folder in File Explore", then you will get the ".winmd" file's path and copy it.

After that, right-click your UWP project and click "add-reference" and open the "Reference Manager", click the "Browse..." button, then, you could input the ".winmd" file's path and add reference to this ".winmd" file.

[image]